# $4\times ABCDE = EDCBA$: Four times a five digit integer is that integer backwards.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle

A student gave me this puzzle the other day. Where $A,B,C,D,E$ are distinct digits, and where $A,E\ne0$, what 5 digit integer satisfies the condition below?

$$4\times ABCDE=EDCBA$$

What I'm interested in isn't the answer per se. I'm looking for the *most efficient* solution - the least number of logical moves necessary to solve the problem.

Comment: Clearly $A$ is even and so $A=2$ to avoid a carry in multiplication, so $E\ge 4A$ is $8$ or $9$ but $4\times 9 = 36$ so  $E=8$, so $B=0$ or $1$ to avoid a carry in multiplication, but $EDC02$ is not a multiple of $4$ so $B=1$ ...

Comment: Since Henry has already given the logical solution, I will only add that years ago I designed a web page to solve and _create_ cryptarithms. It is [here](http://www.iread.it/cryptarithms.php)

Comment: ... so $D=2$ or $7$ to give $4 \times 21CD8 = 8DC12$ but $D \not = A$ so $D=7$, and the only $C$ which fits is $C=9$

Comment: @Henry We got the answer at the same time and so, I was typing the answer while you were typing the comment. ..

Comment: I have to say, hitting refresh was like watching you two type on live stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $A$ is even and so $A=2$ to avoid a carry in multiplication, so $E≥4$ is $8$ or $9$ but $4×9=36$ so $E=8$ (credit to the comment on the question). 
 $B<3$ for $E=8$ . $B$ is odd since $B=4D+3$ where $3$ is the carry. So, $B=1$  and $D=2$ or $7$ 
 If $D=2$, carry under $B$ should have been $8$ which is impossible with multiplication by $4$. So, $D=7$ 
 Now, it's easy to derive $4C+3=3*10+C$ and $C=9$ . 
 The number is $21978$