# Solution of cryptarithmetic problems using simultaneous equations modulo 10

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, puzzle

Recently I came accross the [following puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651699/4-times-abcde-edcba-four-times-a-five-digit-integer-is-that-integer-backwar):

Where ,,,, are distinct digits, and where ,≠0, what 5 digit integer satisfies the condition below?

$$\text{ABCDE} \times 4 = \text{EDCBA}$$

I now know that puzzles of this form are called "cryptarithmetic" puzzles, or "cryptarithms."

The two methods I've seen people use to solve these puzzles are:

1. Brute force computer search, and
2. Induction-based logic, e.g., [example answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/311216/win-vineeth).

I've been wondering if there is a different way to find solutions, using simultaneous equations.

My first attempt was to set up a matrix system for the numbers in their base 10 representation. I tried the following equation, with the intention of rearranging and solving for the unknowns:

$$
4 \times
  \begin{bmatrix}
    10^4 &  &  &  &  \\
     & 10^3 &  &  &  \\
     &  & 10^2 &  &  \\
     &  &  & 10^1 &  \\
     &  &  &  & 10^0
  \end{bmatrix} 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    A \\
    B \\
    C \\
    D \\
    E
  \end{bmatrix} 
=
  \begin{bmatrix}
     &  &  &  & 10^4 \\
     &  &  & 10^3 &  \\
     &  & 10^2 &  &  \\
     & 10^1 &  &  &  \\
    10^0 &  &  &  & 
  \end{bmatrix} 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    A \\
    B \\
    C \\
    D \\
    E
  \end{bmatrix} 
$$

However I quickly realized that this wouldn't work, because multiplying certain digits by 4 result in a two digit number, meaning that each of the different digit equations cannot be treated separately.

I came to the conclusion that I would have to account for carrying remainders over to the equation that represented the next power of 10. I came up with an idea of how to do this with modulo arithmetic:

\begin{align*}
A &= (4 \cdot E ) \mod 10 \\
B &= (4 \cdot D + x_1 ) \mod 10 \\
C &= (4 \cdot C + x_2 ) \mod 10 \\
D &= (4 \cdot B + x_3 ) \mod 10 \\
E &= (4 \cdot A + x_4 ) \mod 10 
\end{align*}

... where $x_1,\dots x_4$ are the following divisors:

\begin{align*}
x_1 &= \lfloor(4 \cdot E)/10 \rfloor \\
x_2 &= \lfloor(4 \cdot E + x_1)/10 \rfloor \\
x_3 &= \lfloor(4 \cdot E + x_2)/10 \rfloor \\
x_4 &= \lfloor(4 \cdot E + x_3)/10 \rfloor 
\end{align*}

This is starting to feel like a manageable approach, but I'm unsure how to progress with solving this system of equations. If I know the values $x_1,\dots x_4$ *a priori*, I can quite easily solve the modulo system of equations with standard techniques. (I've checked this in Mathematica and I found the correct solution.) However it's not clear how to modify the system of equations to also solve for the values $x_1,\dots x_4$. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not easily. Often the implicit condition that digits are between 0 and 9 is crucial to the solution, and this isn't that simple to convey in a matrix. IE what you have is the linear equation $39996A+396B+3C-960D-9996E = 0$, so are searching for answers within a 4-dimension space.

Comment: Personally, my approach is *random insights*.  For example, $~4e \equiv a \pmod{10} \implies a \in \{2,4,6,8\}.~$  Further, since the rhs of the original equation has only 5 digits, you know immediately that $~e > a.~$  In fact, you can immediately conclude that $~a = 2,~$ because $~4 \times 4 > 10.~$ This implies that $~e \in \{3,8\},~$ and that $~4a \leq e \implies e = 8.~$

Comment: Once you use the floor function and the binary mod function, you're no longer working with linear equations, so linear algebra is unlikely to work out well for you. Maybe you can kludge something together, but creating it takes much more time than working the logic.